# Optimizing K-means clustering using Genetic Algorithm

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, genetic-algorithm

I have the following `dataset` (obtained [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/)):

```
----------item survivalpoints weight
1  pocketknife             10      1
2        beans             20      5
3     potatoes             15     10
4       unions              2      1
5 sleeping bag             30      7
6         rope             10      5
7      compass             30      1
```

I  can cluster this dataset into three clusters with `kmeans()` using a binary string as my initial choice of centers. For eg:

```
## 1 represents the initial centers
chromosome = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
## exclude first column (kmeans only support continous data)
cl <- kmeans(dataset[, -1], dataset[chromosome == 1, -1])
## check the memberships
cl$clusters
# [1] 1 3 3 1 2 1 2
```

Using this fundamental concept, I tried it out with `GA` package to conduct the search where I am trying to optimize(minimize) Davies-Bouldin (DB) Index.

```
library(GA)           ## for ga() function
library(clusterSim)   ## for index.DB() function

## defining my fitness function (Davies-Bouldin)
DBI <- function(x) {
        ## converting matrix to vector to access each row
        binary_rep <- split(x, row(x))
        ## evaluate the fitness of each chromsome
        for(each in 1:nrow(x){
            cl <- kmeans(dataset, dataset[binary_rep[[each]] == 1, -1])
            dbi <- index.DB(dataset, cl$cluster, centrotypes = "centroids")
            ## minimizing db
            return(-dbi)
    }
}

g<- ga(type = "binary", fitness = DBI, popSize = 100, nBits = nrow(dataset))
```

Of course (I have no idea what's happening), I received error message of 
`Warning messages:
Error in row(x) : a matrix-like object is required as argument to 'row'`

Here are my questions:

1. How can correctly use the `GA` package to solve my problem?
2. How can I make sure the randomly generated chromosomes contains the same number of `1`s which corresponds to `k` number of clusters (eg. if `k=3` then the chromosome must contain exactly three `1`s)?

Comment: I don't think this approach makes any sense. It likely will not work because k-means too often converges to the exact same solution.

Comment: is there any suggestion you can offer for problem like this? is my dataset too small?

Comment: I don't think GA+k-means *ever* makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on the sense of combining k-means with ga, but I can point out that you had issue in your fitness function. Also, errors are produced when all genes are on or off, so fitness is only calculated when that is not the case:

```
DBI <- function(x) {
  if(sum(x)==nrow(dataset) | sum(x)==0){
    score <- 0
  } else {
    cl <- kmeans(dataset[, -1], dataset[x==1, -1])
    dbi <- index.DB(dataset[,-1], cl=cl$cluster, centrotypes = "centroids")
    score <- dbi$DB
  }

  return(score)
}

g <- ga(type = "binary", fitness = DBI, popSize = 100, nBits = nrow(dataset))
plot(g)
```

[image]

```
g@solution
g@fitnessValue
```

Looks like several gene combinations produced the same "best" fitness value

Comment: I can't tell you how grateful am I for this answer. Yes I would agree that the genes tend to converge to the same solution, but knowing how to apply user-defined fitness is a great start for me. Many thanks!

Comment: Cheers - In case it wasn't clear, be sure that you understand that ga will try to _maximize_ the fitness function, not minimize - as is done in other optimizing algorithms that are based on a cost function.

Comment: which brings me to another question, since `ga` maximize the fitness function, why is it unnecessary to multiple the `score` with -1 in order to minimize it? I have seen in other examples, especially using the `genalg` package where it minimizes the fitness function, therefore, to maximize it, they will just return value multiplied by -1.

Comment: In some cases you may be fitting a function, where you are trying to minimize the difference between observed and predicted values. In order to flip this around to reflect maximizing fitness, you would simply multiply your e.g. sum of residuals by -1. In both cases, you are aiming for the best possible score=0 difference.

Comment: Hi Marc, I have dropped an email (found at your blog) to show you some graphs for discussion since I can't upload photos at the comment box. Mind to take a look? Thanks :)